# React onClick function triggering itself at mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that contains a basic onClick function.

The function is called when the component is rendering (without any click), why is it happening?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Some extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  someFunc = (message) => {
    console.log(message)
  }


  render() {
    return (
       <p onClick={this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>
     )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to append your function like that. You just need to call it by other ways:

```
<p onClick={() => this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>
```

By using this syntax you can call it by `params`.

But your first solution was just passing the function

If your function had no `argument` to pass you could just pass the function like below:

```
<p onClick={this.someFunc}>test</p>
```

Because you need to pass some `arguments` the first one which I mentioned will be your desired one.

> You can read their document for further details: [React Handling
>   Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: It was my pleasure

Answer (score 4):

in React you need to pass unexecuted functions, so either

```
onClick = {this.someFunction}
```

or if you need to pass an argument

```
onClick = {() => this.someFunction('argument')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you write

`<p onClick={this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>`

instead of

`<p onClick={this.someFunc}>test</p>`.

If you put there the `()` the function will be called right on rendering, else only if clicked.

Try this arrow function

`<p onClick={() => this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>`

Not tested, but should work correctly this way.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You are invoking this.someFunc('hello') when you render your class, not when you call your onClick property. To fix it, you should use an arrow function, as so:

```
<p onClick={() => this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>
```

Now if you want to know why this happens, let me clarify what you are doing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Some extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // You define a class method that when called will in turn call the
  // console.log method, passing message as your argument.
  // message will equal 'hello' in your example.
  someFunc = (message) => {
    console.log(message)
  }

  // You define a render method of your class, react will 
  // automatically call this method on render.
  render() {

  // Your render method (which again is called automatically) will return
  // <p onClick={this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>
  // let's see what operations you are performing in this JSX return.
    return (
       // You first define a paragraph html element to be rendered.
       // You then give your element an attribute called onClick.
       // But oh no! You are assigning onClick with the value of: 
       // this.someFunc('hello')
       //
       // That is not good, as what you are in effect saying is:
       // please call the method this.someFunc and pass a single argument: 'hello'
       // then assign the return of that method call to my property named onClick.
       // Therefore, every time you render this class, you are asking
       // javascript to call this function and get its value (which is undefined).
       // So while you think onClick is a function, it is not! it is only a value. 
       // A value which you are asking JavaScript to get for you on each render.
       // This is because in JS, when you write functionName(), 
       // you are literally calling the function at that moment.
       // See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp
       <p onClick={this.someFunc('hello')}>test</p>

       // What you want to do instead is assign your onClick property
       // a function! Not a value! 
       // You want to write, "When I click here, do: this.someFunc('hello')"
       // to do that, you have some options, but the end goal will be the same
       // What you need to do is assign onClick a value, which when called (onClick)
       // will trigger your function! For instance:
       // onClick={() => this.someFunc('hello')}
       // Above we say "on each render, assign the onClick property a value which IS a function!"
       // This is, an unnamed arrow function!
       // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
       // Notice how we have defined an unnamed function that wraps our
       // this.someFunc('hello') and we have NOT
       // immediately called it (no parentheses following the wrapper function)
       // # outer function \() => #inner function \functionName()\ \ <-- No trailing parentheses.
       // Therefore, now the only way to execute your method named
       // this.someFunc('hello') is by calling its wrapper function.
       // And the only way to call that unnamed wrapper function?
       // By invoking your onClick property of your p element.
     )
  }
}
```